Pruning log data with powershell throws null object exception using Where-Object
I'm trying to modify a powershell script to prune its log file at then end of its execution.
this works
$prunedContent =  Get-Content -Path $logfile | Where{[DateTime]($_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf(' '))) -GE $pruneDate}

this throws a null object exception
$prunedContent =  Get-Content -Path $logfile | Where-Object -InputObject [DateTime]($_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf(' '))) -GE $pruneDate

vs code gives me a warning

'Where' is an alias of 'Where-Object'. Alias can introduce possible problems and make scripts hard to maintain. Please consider changing alias to its full content.

how can I make the Where-Object work?
I've verified in the debugger that Get-Content is returning the entire contents of the log file.  Each line of the log file is known to start with the formatted date/time as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

-InputObject is the object that gets bound from pipeline and becomes $_ in the context of the -FilterScript scriptblock: .. | Where-Object { ... $_ <- this is InputObject }. What you had as first snippet is exactly how your code should look. You don't need to bind -InputObject manually, usually this parameter name by convention means that the object is meant to be bound from pipeline.

thank you.  is it likely based on the vs code guidance that Where{ ... } will be deprecated

nah Where isn't deprecated, likely what you see is a recommendation to not use aliases, because Where is an alias of Where-Object so by changing that you shouldn't see that recommendation anymore

A common issue arises on the Windows platform when someone using where in  PowerShell script thinks that they are using where.exe. The same think happens with the PowerShell developer uses dir and does not realize that it is an alias for Get-ChildItem.

The warning you see, AvoidUsingCmdletAliases, is just a PSScriptAnalyzer rule that recommends not using aliases in your scripts. It's simply telling you that:
$prunedContent = Get-Content -Path $logfile | Where { [DateTime]($_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf(' '))) -GE $pruneDate }

Should be:
$prunedContent = Get-Content -Path $logfile | Where-Object { [DateTime]($_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf(' '))) -GE $pruneDate }


thank you.  retested and it worked.  I guess I was overthinking how to add in the -InputObject switch
